# Searching Criteria in SharePoint JSOM with the help of CamlQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, jsom

Suppose i want to replicate following Sql condition in CamlQuery in JSOM

The Condition is:

```
WHERE
    @StudName IS NULL  OR [StudentName] LIKE '%'+@StudName+'%'
```

In above condition the @StudName contains the any character/character set.
[StudentName] will be the Column Name in table.

I want to convert it in JSOM CamlQuery!

Comment: Use the CAMLDesigner: https://www.biwug.be/resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CAML Query, there is no possible criteria as `LIKE`, so you can use `Contains` or `BeginsWith`

Look at this threads/article:

[SharePoint list CAML query using CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870314/sharepoint-list-caml-query-using-contains)

[Using CAML "BeginsWith" in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/begins-with-using-caml-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically-u/)

Also you need to check your `StudName` field as a `null` or not before going for CAML query. So consider below conversion for your CAML query:

```
function retrieveListItems() {
  if(StudName != null){ // StudName is the variable of your column StudName
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Your List Name here');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" +
                              "<Query>" + 
                                  "<Where>"+
                                      "<Contains>"+
                                          "<FieldRef Name='Title' />"+
                                          "<Value Type='Text'>" + StudName + "</Value>" +
                                      "</Contains>" +
                                   "</Where>" + 
                              "</Query>" +
                              "<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>" + 
                          "</View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) { 
    // Your Code Here 
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
    // Your Code Here 
}
```

**Update**:
Check for multiple fields with Contains CAML query is as below:

```
<Or>
    <Or>
        <Contains>
           <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
           <Value Type='Text'>2</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
           <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
           <Value Type='Text'>4</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Or>
    <Or>
        <Contains>
           <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
           <Value Type='Text'>2</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
           <FieldRef Name='Field4' />
           <Value Type='Text'>4</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Or>
</Or>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can we pass more than <FieldRef> in between <Contains>?
I just try it out for more than one <FieldRef> in between <Contains> but getting error!
If there is a solution for multiple Fields, please let me know!

Comment: I have 4 Fields to add in Contains! How can I do this?

Comment: Check my updated answer!